# Javascript - Problem in accessing global variables

Tags: javascript

I want to share values across the two javascript functions but below in second function I am unable to get the value from the global variable

```
// Following two are global variables
    var grid;
    var masterTable;

    function GridCreated(sender, args)
    {
        grid = sender; // setting values
        masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView(); // setting values - Here masterTable has values in it
        masterTable.selectAllItems(true);
    }



    function abc()
    {
        debugger;
        var collectionofordernumber = 0;


               var selectedrows = mastertable.get_selecteditems(); // HERE I UNABLE TO GET THE VALUES FROM MASTERTABLE

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedrows.length; i++)
               {
                   var row = selectedrows[i];
                   var cell = mastertable.getcellbycolumnuniquename(row, "ordernumber")
           collectionofordernumber = collectionofordernumber + "-" + cell.innerhtml;
                }

        document.getelementbyid("hdf1").value = collectionofordernumber;
        alert('I m here');
    }
```

I want to share values across the two javascript functions but below in second function I am unable to get the value from the global variable

Answer (score 8):

You defined the variable `masterTable` but are accessing it with lowercase `mastertable`?